# How to close a QDialog

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, qdialog

I've been trying to close a QDialog window that is branching off of my main window.  The following have not worked for me so far:

```
self.close()
QDialog.close()
```

I tried other commands such as `exit` and `exec_()` with no luck.
The most common error I get is

> [className] object has no attribute 'close'

```
# Creating our window
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Sets up GUI
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        [GUI CODE]      

    # Sets text for parts of GUI
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        [MORE GUI CODE]

    # Function handling screencap on click and metadata for filenames
    def cap_on_Click(arg1,arg2):

        popup = QDialog()
        popup_ui = Ui_Dialog()
        popup_ui.setupUi(popup)
        popup.show()
        sys.exit(popup.exec_())
```

The above is my main window

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):

        [GUI CODE]

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):

        [MORE GUI CODE]

    def button_click(self, arg1):

        self.close()
```

The second block is the dialog window code.  How do I close this dialog window?

Comment: Please follow [these MVCE guidlines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal working example, so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, sorry for the links related to C++, but [Python has the same concept](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html#done).

You can try using the [`reject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#reject) or [`accept`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept) or [`done`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#done) function to close the dialog box. By doing this, you're setting the return value appropriately (`Rejected`, `Accepted` or the one you specify as the argument).

All in all, you should try calling `YourDialog.done(n)` to close the dialog and return `n` and `YourDialog.accept()` or `YourDialog.reject()` when you want it accepted/rejected.

Comment: I've tried analogs like that, but for some reason my dialog isn't defined there.

Comment: @CSnyder, it isn't defined _where_?

Comment: In the Ui_Dialog class, which is where i try to call the     self.close() function.

Comment: @CSnyder, have you tried calling `self.done()` or something like this?

Comment: I've tried every command meant to close windows that I could find, and none of them worked.  I switched over to C++ rather than continue with python. C++ has no such issues that I've run into.

Comment: @CSnyder: how are you supposed to call `close()` on `Ui_Dialog` if it inherits from `object`?  The code generated with Qt Designer should stay unmodified. What you do is you have to use multiple inheritance and make your dialog inherit both from `QDialog` and (untampered with) `Ui_Dialog`. Then you have access both to what was generated and what ships with `QDialog`

Comment: @z33k Exactly z33k

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is that `Ui_Dialog` does not inherit `QDialog`, so `reject()`, `accept()` and `done()` is not defined. I think

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
```

should be changed to

```
class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
```

But I can not test it because minimal working example is not provided.

Comment: i got this right. but in my case, still it doesn't work using dialog.close() nor dialog.done().the window still open

Comment: Please provide minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Chances are that `Ui_Dialog` is automatically generated through pyuic or similar. You shouldn't manually edit that file. I found a good practise to just create a custom class that inherits the `QWidget` / `QDialog` (or analog) **and** `Ui_Dialog`

Answer (score 3):

Since a `QDialog` is a `QWidget`, and a `QWidget` has the `close()` method, I don't understand how it can not work. You should never invoke `popup.exec_()` though, since it will happily require a lot of your code to be reentrant without you realizing it. It is unnecessary - you already have the application event loop running and on the call stack when `cap_on_Click` is executing.

After `popup.show()`, the dialog will be visible and usable until it gets accepted or rejected by the user. Hopefully your design for the dialog connects the button box's `accepted()` and `rejected()` signals to the dialog's `accept()` and `reject()` slots. That is the default behavior of a `QDialog` template provided with Qt Creator and perhaps Qt Designer as well, but you should check it by going into the signal/slot editor mode while viewing the Ui file.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand how either.  I can tell you however that by omitting popup.exec_(), my dialog window does not appear at all.

Comment: @CSnyder Something else is broken, then. Your code as shown seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's over 5months but I choose to drop this comment here, it might be of help to others tomorrow.
To be able to close or cancel an opened dialog box, using only self.close would close the entire program.
use this example:

```py
self.dlg = QDialog(self)
self.dlg.setWindowTitle("Admin")
self.dlg.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)
btnBox = QDialogButtonBox()
btnBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

btnBox.rejected.connect(self.close1)
def close1():
    self.dlg.close()
```